# How to create many comboboxes and not slow down page loading?

Tags: performance, qt, combobox, qml, load

I am trying to create a QML page but loading is very slow, when run on a beaglebone it takes 15 seconds to load.
It is a page that contains 110 combobox, these repeat the list of 65 elements.
I'm sure it can be done in a more efficient way and with the same visual result.

Picture of visual aspect of the page:
[image: Link to a picture of visual aspect of the page]

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Item {
    id: page6
    width: 800
    height: 480
    clip: false
    property alias text19: text19
    
    property alias cbItems: cbItems
    property alias comboBox0: comboBox0
    property alias comboBox1: comboBox1
    property alias comboBox2: comboBox2
    property alias comboBox3: comboBox3
    
    ...
    ...
    ...

    property alias comboBox97: comboBox97
    property alias comboBox98: comboBox98
    property alias comboBox99: comboBox99
    
    property alias rectangle: rectangle
    property alias button: button
    property alias rectangle1: rectangle1
    property alias rectangle2: rectangle2
    property alias gridLayout: gridLayout
    property alias listView: listView
    property alias page6: page6
    anchors.fill: parent
    visible: true
    
    ListModel {
        id: cbItems
        ListElement {
            text: "1"
        }
        ListElement {
            text: "2"
        }
        ListElement {
            text: "3"
        }
        
        ...
        ...
        ...

        }
        ListElement {
            text: "64"
        }
        ListElement {
            text: "65"
        }
    }
    
    Rectangle {
        id: rectangle
        height: 80
        clip: true
        z: 1
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.bottomMargin: 0
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.left: parent.left
        gradient: Gradient {
            GradientStop {
                position: 0
                color: "#eeeeee"
            }
            
            GradientStop {
                position: 1
                color: "#808080"
            }
        }
        
        Button {
            id: button
            text: qsTr("Volver")
            clip: true
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        }
    }
    
    Rectangle {
        id: rectangle2
        width: 200
        height: 100
        clip: false
        z: 1
        visible: false
        gradient: Gradient {
            GradientStop {
                position: 0
                color: "#ffffff"
            }
            
            GradientStop {
                position: 1
                color: "#808080"
            }
        }
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        
        Text {
            id: text19
            text: qsTr("Espere")
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            anchors.fill: parent
            font.pixelSize: 20
        }
    }
    
    Rectangle {
        id: rectangle1
        width: 800
        height: 400
        visible: true
        clip: true
        gradient: Gradient {
            GradientStop {
                position: 0
                color: "#eeeeee"
            }
            
            GradientStop {
                position: 1
                color: "#808080"
            }
        }
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.topMargin: 0
        
        Flickable {
            id: listView
            visible: false
            clip: true
            contentWidth: 800
            anchors.fill: parent
            contentHeight: gridLayout.implicitHeight + 10
            maximumFlickVelocity: 1000
            flickDeceleration: 800
            
            ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {
                policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOn
            }
            
            GridLayout {
                id: gridLayoutM
                clip: true
                anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                columnSpacing: 20
                columns: 2
                
                GridLayout {
                    id: gridLayout
                    clip: true
                    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                    columnSpacing: 10
                    columns: 4
                    
                    Label {
                        text: "Entrada: "
                        font.pixelSize: 20
                    }
                    Label {
                        text: "0"
                        font.pixelSize: 20
                    }
                    Label {
                        text: "Nivel: "
                        font.pixelSize: 20
                    }
                    ComboBox {
                        id: comboBox0
                        width: 400
                        currentIndex: 0
                        model: cbItems
                        
                    }
                    
                    Label {
                        text: "Entrada: "
                        font.pixelSize: 20
                    }
                    Label {
                        text: "1"
                        font.pixelSize: 20
                    }
                    Label {
                        text: "Nivel: "
                        font.pixelSize: 20
                    }
                    ComboBox {
                        id: comboBox1
                        width: 400
                        currentIndex: 1
                        model: cbItems
                    }
                    
                    Label {
                        text: "Entrada: "
                        font.pixelSize: 20
                    }
                    Label {
                        text: "2"
                        font.pixelSize: 20
                    }
                    Label {
                        text: "Nivel: "
                        font.pixelSize: 20
                    }
                    ComboBox {
                        id: comboBox2
                        width: 400
                        currentIndex: 2
                        model: cbItems
                    }
                    
                    Label {
                        text: "Entrada: "
                        font.pixelSize: 20
                    }
                    Label {
                        text: "3"
                        font.pixelSize: 20
                    }
                    Label {
                        text: "Nivel: "
                        font.pixelSize: 20
                    }
                    ComboBox {
                        id: comboBox3
                        width: 400
                        currentIndex: 3
                        model: cbItems
                    }
                    
                    ...                        
                    ...
                    ...

                    Label {
                        text: "Entrada: "
                        font.pixelSize: 20
                    }
                    Label {
                        text: "97"
                        font.pixelSize: 20
                    }
                    Label {
                        text: "Nivel: "
                        font.pixelSize: 20
                    }
                    ComboBox {
                        id: comboBox97
                        width: 400
                        currentIndex: -1
                        model: cbItems
                    }
                    
                    Label {
                        text: "Entrada: "
                        font.pixelSize: 20
                    }
                    Label {
                        text: "98"
                        font.pixelSize: 20
                    }
                    Label {
                        text: "Nivel: "
                        font.pixelSize: 20
                    }
                    ComboBox {
                        id: comboBox98
                        width: 400
                        currentIndex: -1
                        model: cbItems
                    }
                    
                    Label {
                        text: "Entrada: "
                        font.pixelSize: 20
                    }
                    Label {
                        text: "99"
                        font.pixelSize: 20
                    }
                    Label {
                        text: "Nivel: "
                        font.pixelSize: 20
                    }
                    ComboBox {
                        id: comboBox99
                        width: 400
                        currentIndex: -1
                        model: cbItems
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If possible, I recommend using a `ListView` with a model to create those comboboxes, rather than writing each one out. A `ListView` will only create enough delegates as it needs for the visual display. That means it won't create all 100 comboboxes at the same time. So that should speed up the load time. Here's a simplified example:

```
ListView {
    model: 100

    delegate: ComboBox {
        model: cbItems
        ...
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

To add other data to the comboboxes, you will want to use a model. This can be defined in C++ using QAbstractItemModel, or here in QML using a `ListModel` object, or even just an array. [Here's](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-modelview.html) some info on models.

```
// Simple model that just contains the currentIndex of each combobox
property var comboModel: [
    myFunction.readR0(),
    myFunction.readR1(),
    ...
]

ListView {
    model: comboModel

    delegate: ComboBox {
        model: cbItems
        currentIndex: comboModel[index]
        ...
    }
}
```

As for your aliases, I question what you need you them for. To get or set properties on the comboboxes, you should really just be accessing the model, not the comboboxes themselves.

Comment: Okay, but using this form to create ComboBox, how can I reference the id? Earlier I used "property alias comboBox0:  comboBox0" and "comboBox0.currentIndex: myFunction.readR0()", and this is not possible now.